# How to save and load using modelcheckpointcallback in tensorflow 2.4.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using the keras API in tensorflow 2.4.0 to save at different steps my model using this line of code:

```py
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(log_dir, "checkpoint_{epoch:02d}.tf"),
                                   save_freq=train_steps_per_epoch * cfg.log.checkpoint_save_every_epochs,
                                   save_weights_only=False))
```

When the model is saved I encounter some warnings:

```
[2021-03-17 12:11:09,974][absl][WARNING] - Found untraced functions such as nl_0_layer_call_fn, nl_0_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, nl_1_layer_call_fn, nl_1_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, conv2d_layer_call_fn while saving (showing 5 of 280). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
```

And when I load the model using this line of code:

```
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(os.path.join(train_dir, f'checkpoint_{cfg.training.checkpoint_epoch:02d}.tf'))
```

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run/linear_classifier_evaluation.py", line 51, in run
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(os.path.join(train_dir, f'checkpoint_{cfg.training.checkpoint_epoch:02d}.tf'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 212, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 138, in load
    keras_loader.load_layers(compile=compile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 376, in load_layers
    node_metadata.metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 417, in _load_layer
    obj, setter = self._revive_from_config(identifier, metadata, node_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 434, in _revive_from_config
    self._revive_graph_network(metadata, node_id) or
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 471, in _revive_graph_network
    inputs=[], outputs=[], name=config['name'])
KeyError: 'name'
```

I've searched online this error and I've read people suggesting to implement get_config and from_config methods in my model class but I am not using the H5 format so I shouldn't have to do that if I understood correctly the [keras tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) and others solutions where for tf1.x.

I would gladly welcome any help or suggestions on where to look.

Comment: In your model, is there any custom layer?

Comment: Yes my model is composed of a ResNet block on which I put on top a sequential keras model composed of a sync batch norm and a classifier. Although I shouldn't have to use the custom object parameter in my loading option if i'm not saving using the h5 format rght ?

Comment: No, (AFAIK), you should.

Comment: Ok thank you I will work on that then

Comment: get/from_config are not specific to the H5 format, you need to implement those.

Comment: I don't think this is true. The TensorFlow documentation states clearly that when storing it in the new format as opposed to h5 it can trace all calls in the custom layers and does not require get_config and from_config.

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue. Can you please share standalone code to replicate your issue? So that we can try to help you. Thanks!